# If 2 cells are blank (ISBLANK)

Tags: excel

I've got a formula to calculate average of two cells. If L4 is blank it gets J4. It works fine.

`=IF(ISBLANK(L4), J4, IF(L4 = 0, J4, ((J4/2) + (L4/2))))`

But I need to add one more column to this formula. I need to calculate average of 3 cells.(lets say N4 to third column)

If N4 is empty it must get average of L4 and J4.
If N4 and L4 are empty it must only get J4.

I've tried several things but no conclusion.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So use and(isblank(n4),isblank(L4)) and more if(). Nice little logic puzzle using if() inside if().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it as below...
`=IF(ISBLANK(N4), IF(ISBLANK(L4), J4, (J4/2+L4/2)), (J4/3) + (L4/3) + (N4/3))`

If you are considering `N4 = 0` and `L4 = 0` the same as blank, you can add an `OR` condition as well like below

`=IF(OR(ISBLANK(N4), N4=0), IF(OR(ISBLANK(L4), N4=0), J4, (J4/2+L4/2)), (J4/3) + (L4/3) + (N4/3))`

Comment: I tweaked your calculation a bit like that and it worked.

`=IF(OR(ISBLANK(N4), N4=0), IF(AND(ISBLANK(L4), N4=0), J4, (J4/2+L4/2)), (J4/3) + (L4/3) + (N4/3))`

I used AND instead of OR at second one.